# Extract value from an interval from cut()

Tags: r, max

In R, for the function `cut()`

```
> cut(c(0,1),2)
[1] (-0.001,0.5] (0.5,1]     
Levels: (-0.001,0.5] (0.5,1]
```

How do I extract a number from an interval, say the `max` of `(-0.001,0.5]`?

Answer (score 3):

We can extract the numbers with `str_extract` and then convert it to `numeric` and get the `max`.  As the numeric part includes digits `[0-9]` with `.` including negative numbers, the pattern to match can be `"-?[0-9.]+"`

```
library(stringr)
sapply(str_extract_all(v1, "-?[0-9.]+"), function(x) max(as.numeric(x)))
#[1] 0.5 1.0
```

#### data

```
v1 <- cut(c(0,1),2)
```